# How the year affects Area Solar Radiation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, solar-radiation

How choosing a different year in "Area Solar Radiation" affects the calculation of the radiation? 
I understand that months change some parameters in the calculation formulas, but what about the year? What's the difference between choosing 2012 or 2013, or some other year?

Comment: No effect effect, unless you are going to account for weather condition and odd years

Comment: How can I account weather condition in solar radiation calculation?

Comment: I think that this may be a question better asked at the [earthscience.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: The year indication seems not to have any influence. I have run area solar radiation for `MultipleDays` for both 2012 (leap year) and 2013 (no leap year) and got back exactly same radiation values. You can try this on yous subset data as well. More on ArcGIS help: `The year value for time configuration is used to determine a leap year. It does not have any other influence on the solar radiation analysis as the calculations are a function of the time period determined by Julian days.` http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/area-solar-radiation.htm

Comment: Many software offer just artificially generated data, based on some long-term averages or simple modelling. In reality year-to-year variability in global horizontal irradiation (GHI) can variate significantly. Typical values can be: in arid regions is up to ±5%, tropical, monsoon and boreal regions up to ±10%, more extreme years even over ±15%. You can consult some [maps](https://solargis.com/products/monitor/solar-performance-maps) on Solargis website.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what part of earth are you located. If you are within the mid and tropical latitudes solar radiation is constant. This means we always get 12 hr of light and 12 hrs of darkness not like the upper and lower latitudes (poles) where solar radiation intensity changes depending of time of the year.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.  The OP is asking how year affects solar radiation not position on the earth.